# Claryfing gitignore documentation

Tags: git

I don't understand some statements in `gitignore` documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

The parts that I don't understand appear in **bold**. My questions are in italic.

1. > If the pattern ends with a slash, **it is removed for the purpose of the following description**"

*What is removed? What is the "following description" ?*

2. > If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file [..] **Otherwise**, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob

*"Otherwise" from what? Are they contrasting "with" and "without" slash in the pattern? If so, how are the two cases treated differently?*

3. > A trailing "/**" matches everything inside.

*Is that the same result as a trailing `/` without the asterisks? It looks like it from what I can see in the bullet point about the trailing slash ("foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it").*

Do you also find this documentation confusing? If so, what would be the best way to signal it to the Git team? (mailing list or issue tracker?).

Comment: ofc, / is removed. Otherwise = pattern contains /

Comment: _"ends with a slash"_ - the slash is removed?

Comment: *"Do you also find this documentation confusing?"* -- absolutely not. What do you find confusing in the expression *"the following description"*?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between cases in your point 2 too. “treats it as a shell glob pattern” and “treats the pattern as a shell glob”. The wording of the difference could be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I also found the old description very confusing. I have created a PR to improve the rules. I think its much better now.

Here an excerpt of the new [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

> The slash / is used as the directory separator. Separators may occur
>   at the beginning, middle or end of the .gitignore search pattern.
>
> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the
>   pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the
>   particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also
>   match at any level below the .gitignore level.
>
> If there is a separator at the end of the pattern then the pattern
>   will only match directories, otherwise the pattern can match both
>   files and directories.
>
> For example, a pattern doc/frotz/ matches doc/frotz directory, but not
>   a/doc/frotz directory; however frotz/ matches frotz and a/frotz that
>   is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file).

---

Nevertheless here is the answer to your questions:

> If the pattern ends with a slash, **it is removed for the purpose of the following description**"
>
> *What is removed? What is the "following description" ?*

It means that trailing slashes are excluded when slashes are mentioned. But it actually effects only the next paragraph.

> If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file [..] **Otherwise**, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob
>
> *"Otherwise" from what? Are they contrasting "with" and "without" slash in the pattern? If so, how are the two cases treated differently?*

So with the above explanation in mind the first paragraph means this:

> If the pattern contains no slash '/' other then a trailing slash, then the pattern will match in all directories.

In other words, `foo/` will match `/bar/foo/` and `foo` will match `/bar/foo`

And the "Otherwise part" means:

> If the pattern contains a slash '/' other then a trailing slash,    it is always considered from the root.

In other words, `foo/bar`  will match `/foo/bar` but not `/bar/foo/bar`.

> A trailing "/**" matches everything inside.
>
> *Is that the same result as a trailing `/` without the asterisks? It looks like it from what I can see in the bullet point about the trailing slash ("foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it").*

There is a subtle difference. `foo/` will ignore the folder, while `foo/**` will ignore the folder and its content.

So if this is your file structure:

```
  .gitignore
  foo
    ├── bar.json
    └── foo.txt
```

then the following .gitignore file would track everything:

```
foo/
!foo/
```

However

```
foo/**
!foo/
```

would track nothing. Because you first ignore all files, then you unignore the folder `/foo` but since the folder has no trackable files it is empty and empty folders are not tracked by git.

Answer (score 0):

> > If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description"
>
> What is removed?

The trailing slash.

> What is the "following description" ?

The rest of the man page, especially the rest of the section "PATTERN FORMAT".

> > If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file [..] Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob
>
> "Otherwise" from what?

Please note that "Otherwise" starts a new bullet point hence it's not limited to the point you've quoted. It means "Otherwise" from all ifs from the beginning of the section "PATTERN FORMAT".

> > A trailing "/**" matches everything inside.
>
> Is that the same result as a trailing / without the asterisks?

I think so.

> Do you also find this documentation confusing?

Not at all, in practical sense: I have never ignored anything I didn't want to ignore nor I accidentally tracked what I wanted to ignore.

> If so, what would be the best way to signal it to the Git team? (mailing list or issue tracker?).

They [direct users](https://github.com/git/git#readme) to the mailing list.